# Spring SAML CurrentUserHandler not working

Tags: spring, saml

I have implemented the SAML configurations as mentioned in https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample but its not populating the '@CurrentUser User user' in the landing controller method. loadUserBySAML() of SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl gets SAMLCredential properly.

I have XML based MvcConfig,whereas the WebSecurityConfig(for SAML) is Java based Config. Have added 'bean class = "CurrentUserHandlerClass' in 'mvc:argumentresolvers'. So while invoking the landing Controller method below exception is thrown

[image]
please help me out and comment it if you require something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its now solved as the controller URL was missing in the securitychainfilter

Comment: Which means what, exactly? I'm encountering the same issue and would like to know how you added your controller URL to the SecurityChainFilter.